# three.js — How do I select mesh outside of loader?

Tags: javascript, three.js, scope

I want to change the material of a mesh which I can easily do within [three.js](https://threejs.org/docs)'s mesh loader. However, once the loader is complete, I can no longer access it from an external function. It must be a scoping issue that I haven't been able to figure out.

**This works** (But I can't use it this way):

```
var loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
    loader.load('model.glb', function (gltf) {
    scene.add(gltf.scene);

    // Material changed below
    var newMat = new THREE.TextureLoader().load(something.jpg);
    gltf.scene.traverse(function (node) {
            node.material = newMat;
    });

});
```

**This doesn't. How can I fix it?**

```
var loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
loader.load('model.glb', function (gltf) {
    scene.add(gltf.scene);
});

function textureSwap(){
    var newMat = new THREE.TextureLoader().load(something.jpg);
    gltf.scene.traverse(function (node) {
            node.material = newMat;
    });
}

textureSwap();  // Material should change when calling this
```

The error is 'gltf is not defined'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The error is 'gltf is not defined'.

This happens because `gltf` is only valid within the `onLoad()` callback. You can easily avoid the runtime error by assigning `gltf.scene` to a variable like `model` which is declared in a higher scope.

```
var model;

var loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
loader.load('model.glb', function (gltf) {
    scene.add(gltf.scene);
    model = gltf.scene;
});

function textureSwap(){
    var newMat = new THREE.TextureLoader().load(something.jpg);
    model.traverse(function (node) {
        node.material = newMat;
    });
}
```

You have to ensure that `textureSwap()` is only called after the loading process has finished. To make the function more robust, you can do this:

```
function textureSwap(){
    if ( model ) {
        var newMat = new THREE.TextureLoader().load(something.jpg);
        model.traverse(function (node) {
            node.material = newMat;
        });
    }
}
```